# pass location of a file in FTP through intent

Tags: android, ftp

I want to pass the URL of a file located in FTP using intent from my android application to open it in google chrome. I am trying to pass it to  google chrome application browser but it does not include a colon after the keyword **ftp**.
I am passing

***"http://ftp://demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/"***

and it displays the following link in the URL box

***"http://ftp//demo.wftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf/"***

It is missing a colon after **ftp** and I want to pass that colon also in the URL.

The code I used is

```
    String url = "http://ftp://demo.ftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf";
    String uri = "googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(uri));

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the correct link:

```
String url = "ftp://demo.ftpserver.com/download/manual_en.pdf";
```

Here is the way I would do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/"));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
```

Comment: Puh it took me really 7 minutes to find an open ftp server to verify my answer. Just use "my" url as uri and it should work

Comment: can you provide the code in Java as I am not familiar to Kotlin

Comment: I converted the code back to Java. By the way you should give it a try.

Comment: This doesn't open the given URL. It opens a blank tab. On adding **http://** it opens the URL shown in the question. Can you provide me with a solution to pass an extra colon after **http://**?